# Getting see through ribbons on time-series in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, time-series, rect

So I have been trying to get semi-sheer ribbons onto a time-series plot. I have done the same for bar-plots using ggplot which was pretty effective BUT due to the size of the data I am working with for the time-series I can't type it out into a dataframe (working from a microsoft excel comma separated values file loaded into R). 
So looking to either be able to convert this to a dataframe OR plot semi-sheer blocks onto it.

Code and associated error messages below.

```
plot(Nitrate_Interp~RiverWensum$Rdates, type="l", xlab="Time", ylab="Nitrate (mg N L)", las=1, 
col="black")
rect((RiverWensum$Rdates)-1,lower_yNr,(RiverWensum$Rdates)+1,upper_yNr, density=30, col="#FF000080", 
border="red")
#defining the colour
mycol <- rgb(225,0,0,max=225,alpha=125,names="red.5")
mycol
red.5 = "#FF000080"
#error given when script run:
Error in rgb(255, 0, 0, max = 220, alpha = 125, names = "red50") : 
colour intensity 1.15909, not in [0,1]
```

Thanks inn advance

Comment: This needs clarification- without a reproducible example there is little chance of finding a solution

Comment: I'm not sure how to give a reproducible example as I don't know how to plot Rdates without importing excel sheets (and without the rdates (if x and y are both numbers) this problem is easier to solve with polygon).  ...  basically no matter what colour I try to define it comes out as solid black (with a red border to the rect it will come out red). Am i missing a package or something?

Answer (score 2):

The `rgb()` function has a setting of `maxColorValue`, not `max`, which you should set to your chosen max value (though it seems to work and doesn't seem to be your problem). Looking at the error:

```
Error in rgb(255, 0, 0, max = 220...
```

...your max is less than your red value too so it will not work. 255/220>1

Comment: Ah okay - replotted with this change and the red colour is still coming out as just a solid opaque block...any suggestions?

Comment: What change did you make?

Comment: Just changed the max bit: mycol <- rgb(225,0,0,maxColorValue=225,alpha=125,names="red.5")

Comment: Well that's what you define... what are you trying to make if *not* opaque red?

Comment: I'm trying to make the rectangle kind of see through so the plot behind it is visible through. So i wanted a 50% opacity red hence the 125 alpha

Comment: I use your input for rgb here and it works fine... `plot(x = 1, pch = 16, cex = 9, col = rgb(225, 0, 0, maxColorVal = 225, alpha = 125, names = "red.5"))`

Comment: Or better shown by this... `plot(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, pch = 16, cex = 2); polygon(x= c(0,0.7,0.7,0,0), y = c(0.2,0.2,0.7,0.7,0.2), col = rgb(225, 0, 0, maxColorVal = 225, alpha = 125, names = "red.5"))`

Comment: Code that reproduces the problem would be really useful

Comment: plot(Nitrate_Interp~RiverWensum$Rdates, type="l", xlab="Time", ylab="Nitrate (mg N L)", las=1, col="black")
rect((RiverWensum$Rdates)-1,lower_yNr,(RiverWensum$Rdates)+1,upper_yNr, col=rgb(225,0,0,maxColorVal=225,alpha=125,names="red.5"), border="#FF000080")

Comment: that code (^) produces a solid red rectangle on my line graph, rather than a see through one

Comment: For some more context: my y axis is numerical values but my x axis is Rdates (makes plotting a polygon instead of rect more difficult)